# how to use typescript utility "conditional types" in a api response

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I want to improve my custom typing in an API response using the utility "conditional types" such that if the response is successful, the response match the type "Success". Otherwise, the response should match the type "Error".

```
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Fruits {
  id: number;
  color: string;
}

type Data = [] | User[] | Fruits[];

type ApiResponse<T> = T extends Data ? { data: T; message: string } : undefined;

interface Success<T extends Data> {
  status: "loaded";
  data: T;
}

interface Error {
  status: "error";
  data: null;
}

type Status<T> = T extends Data ? Success<T> : Error;

type LoadDataObj<T> = {
  successful: boolean;
  message: string;
} & Status<T>;

function setResponse<T extends Data | undefined>(
  response?: ApiResponse<T>
): LoadDataObj<T> {
  return {
    successful: !!response,
    message: response?.message ?? "",
    data: response?.data ?? null,
    status: response ? "loaded" : "error"
  } 
  as LoadDataObj<T>;
  // as unknown as LoadDataObj<T>;  // if i remove this comment it works
}

const response = setResponse({ data: [{ id: 1, name: "bob" }], message: "data received" });
const responseEmpty = setResponse({ data: [], message: "data is empty" });
const responseError = setResponse();
console.log("response", response);
console.log("responseEmpty", responseEmpty);
console.log("responseError", responseError);
```

Currently i get this error message in the body of functions:

```
Conversion of type '{ successful: boolean; message: string; data: User[] | Fruits[] | null; status: "loaded" | "error"; }' to type 'LoadDataObj<T>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type '{ successful: boolean; message: string; data: User[] | Fruits[] | null; status: "loaded" | "error"; }' is not comparable to type 'Status<T>'.ts(2352)
```

Comment: Use function overloading. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/Na2vBm)

Comment: What `message` do you expect if `data` is an empty array ?

Comment: the property `message`  is not importat. i want just understand how to use `conditional types` in thie code that i have posted

Comment: How about my first comment with function overloading, does it work for you ?

Comment: yes but i don't understand what your code does.

Comment: It is function overloading. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Fruits {
  id: number;
  color: string;
}

type ApiData = User[] | Fruits[];

type ApiResponse<T extends ApiData> = { data: T; message: string }

interface Success<T extends ApiData> {
  successful: true
  status: "loaded";
  data: T;
} 

interface Error {
  successful: false
  status: "error";
  data: undefined;
}

type LoadDataObj<T extends ApiData> =  (Success<T> | Error) & {
  message: string
}

export const setResponse = <T extends ApiData>(
  response?: ApiResponse<T>
): LoadDataObj<T> => {
  return {
    successful: !!response,
    message: response?.message ?? 'some error message',
    data: response?.data ?? undefined,
    status: response ? 'loaded' : 'error'
  } as LoadDataObj<T>
};

const response = setResponse({ data: [{ id: 1, name: "bob" }], message: "OK" });

if (response.successful) {
  /*
    const success: SuccessResponse<{
      id: number;
      name: string;
    }[]> & {
        message: string;
    }
  */
  const success = response
} else {
  /*
    const error: ErrorResponse & {
      message: string;
    }
  */
  const error = response
}
```

Comment: i don't want use unions